# Use Windows SetupAPI to get USB Device Descriptor

Tags: windows, setupapi

I was wondering if it is possible to get the USB device descriptor with the SetupAPI functions (like `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`)?
Thank you!

**EDIT**

So far I am only able to receive the windows *friendly* name:

```
SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo, &DeviceInfoData, SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
            &dwPropertyRegDataType, (BYTE*)szDesc, sizeof(szDesc), &dwSize)
```

Comment: what you have in input ?

Comment: @RbMm I am receiving the Name that's in the driver and not the USB Device Descriptor using the code above.

Comment: i ask - what data you have at begin.

Comment: Could you elaborate what data you mean exactly? I have `hDevInfo` which I got from `hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs((LPGUID)&oGUID, NULL, NULL, (DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE));`

Answer (score 6):

we need have/got string representing [*Device Instance ID*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-instance-ids) of a device. with this we first obtains a device instance handle to the device node via [`CM_Locate_DevNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538742(v=vs.85).aspx) and then call [`CM_Get_DevNode_Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh780218(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`DEVPKEY_NAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff543530(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The retrieved property value is the same as the value of the
>   **DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName** device property, if
>   **DEVPKEY_Device_FriendlyName** is set. Otherwise, the value of
>   **DEVPKEY_NAME** is same as the value of the **DEVPKEY_Device_DeviceDesc**
>   device property.

```
static volatile UCHAR guz;

CONFIGRET PrintFriendlyNameByDeviceID(PWSTR DeviceID)
{
    DEVINST dnDevInst;

    CONFIGRET status = CM_Locate_DevNodeW(&dnDevInst, DeviceID, CM_LOCATE_DEVNODE_NORMAL);

    if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 16;

        PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

        DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

        union {
            PVOID pv;
            PWSTR sz;
            PBYTE pb;
        };

        do 
        {
            if (cb < rcb)
            {
                rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
            }

            status = CM_Get_DevNode_PropertyW(dnDevInst, &DEVPKEY_NAME, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

            if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
            {
                if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
                {
                    DbgPrint("NAME = %S\n", sz);
                }
                else
                {
                    status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
                }
            }

        } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);
    }

    return status;
}
```

if we have the string that identifies the device interface instance - we can obtaining the device instance identifier from it via call [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh780218(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542532(v=vs.85).aspx) key and then call `PrintFriendlyNameByDeviceID`

```
CONFIGRET PrintFriendlyNameByInterface(PCWSTR pszDeviceInterface)
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 64;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    DEVPROPTYPE PropertyType;

    CONFIGRET status;

    union {
        PVOID pv;
        PWSTR DeviceID;
        PBYTE pb;
    };

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            rcb = cb = RtlPointerToOffset(pv = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_PropertyW(pszDeviceInterface, &DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId, &PropertyType, pb, &rcb, 0);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            if (PropertyType == DEVPROP_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                DbgPrint("DeviceID = %S\n", DeviceID);

                status = PrintFriendlyNameByDeviceID(DeviceID);
            }
            else
            {
                status = CR_WRONG_TYPE;
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);

    return status;
}
```

and at begin we have 2 choice: of just retrieves a list of device instance IDs via call [`CM_Get_Device_ID_List`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538415(v=vs.85).aspx) with `CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLASS|CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT` and use `"{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}"` as filter - this is string representation of well known `GUID_DEVCLASS_USB` defined in `devguid.h` :

```
void PrintFriendlyNames(PCWSTR pszFilter)
{
    CONFIGRET status;
    ULONG len = 0, cb = 0, rcb;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    PWSTR buf = 0;

    do 
    {
        if (status = CM_Get_Device_ID_List_SizeW(&len, pszFilter, CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLASS|CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (cb < (rcb = len * sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {
            len = (cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = (PWSTR)alloca(rcb - cb), stack)) / sizeof(WCHAR);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_ID_ListW(pszFilter, buf, len, CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_CLASS|CM_GETIDLIST_FILTER_PRESENT);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            while (*buf)
            {
                DbgPrint("DeviceID = %S\n", buf);

                PrintFriendlyNameByDeviceID(buf);

                buf += 1 + wcslen(buf);
            }
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);
}
PrintFriendlyNames(L"{36fc9e60-c465-11cf-8056-444553540000}");
```

or enumerate device interfaces via [CM_Get_Device_Interface_List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538463(v=vs.85).aspx) and call `PrintFriendlyNameByInterface` for every device interface.

```
void PrintFriendlyNames(PGUID InterfaceClassGuid)
{
    CONFIGRET status;
    ULONG len = 0, cb = 0, rcb;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    PWSTR buf = 0;

    do 
    {
        if (status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&len, InterfaceClassGuid, 0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
        {
            break;
        }

        if (cb < (rcb = len * sizeof(WCHAR)))
        {
            len = (cb = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = (PWSTR)alloca(rcb - cb), stack)) / sizeof(WCHAR);
        }

        status = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(InterfaceClassGuid, 0, buf, len, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT);

        if (status == CR_SUCCESS)
        {
            while (*buf)
            {
                DbgPrint("Interface = %S\n", buf);

                PrintFriendlyNameByInterface(buf);

                buf += 1 + wcslen(buf);
            }
        }

    } while (status == CR_BUFFER_SMALL);
}
```

you can use say [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545972(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
PrintFriendlyNames(const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE));
```

the result of methods (which devices /interfaces) will be listed can be different. say om my comp when enum by `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_USB_DEVICE`:

```
Interface = \\?\USB#VID_046D&PID_C52E#5&18d671f8&0&4#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
DeviceID = USB\VID_046D&PID_C52E\5&18d671f8&0&4
NAME = USB Composite Device
Interface = \\?\USB#VID_051D&PID_0002#5B1120T12418__#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
DeviceID = USB\VID_051D&PID_0002\5B1120T12418__
NAME = American Power Conversion USB UPS
Interface = \\?\USB#VID_045E&PID_077B#5&18d671f8&0&3#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}
DeviceID = USB\VID_045E&PID_077B\5&18d671f8&0&3
NAME = USB Input Device
```

and when enum by `GUID_DEVCLASS_USB` string filter:

```
DeviceID = USB\VID_1F75&PID_0916\120709860570000024
NAME = USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID = USB\ROOT_HUB30\4&33ed72c&0&0
NAME = USB Root Hub (xHCI)
DeviceID = USB\VID_0951&PID_168F\001A92053B6A0CA101340008
NAME = USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID = PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_A2AF&SUBSYS_7A741462&REV_00\3&11583659&0&A0
NAME = Intel(R) USB 3.0 eXtensible Host Controller - 1.0 (Microsoft)
DeviceID = USB\VID_046D&PID_C52E\5&18d671f8&0&4
NAME = USB Composite Device
```